# React ApexCharts update chart with interval

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am building a react app that will display a few charts (with ApexCharts) that need to be updated constantly from an api call. They will display sensor data from different sources.

I have the chart styled and configured as I need it, but if I update the data by changing a state array within a `setInterval` expression, within a couple of iterations the chart starts behaving strangely, like if there were conflicting updates at the same time.

This is the App.js file in CodeSandBox:

```
//App.js
export default function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 30 + 1)) + 30;
      let array = [...data, val];
      array.shift();
      updateData(array);
    }, 2000);
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChartViewer data={data} title="Product Trends by Month" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is the `ChartViewer` component:

```
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

export default function ApexChart(props) {
  const series = [
    {
      name: "xx",
      data: props.data
    }
  ];
  const options = {
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: "line",
      zoom: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 2,
      curve: "smooth"
    },
    colors: ["#210124"],
    fill: {
      type: "gradient",
      gradient: {
        shadeIntensity: 1,
        inverseColors: true,
        gradientToColors: ["#DB162F"],
        opacityFrom: 1,
        opacityTo: 1,
        type: "vertical",
        stops: [0, 30]
      }
    }
  }
  return (
    <div id="chart">
      <Chart options={options} series={series} type="line" height={350} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, here is the CodeSandbox Link, where you can see the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-monad-5c1i3?file=/src/ChartViewer.js:41-839

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing no dependencies to useEffect. This makes it run on every render which makes your charts redraw very often.

To fix this you have to change you useEffect a bit:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 30 + 1)) + 30;
      let array = [...data, val];
      array.shift();
      updateData(array);
    }, 2000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(interval); // clear the interval in the cleanup function
    };
  }, [data]); // pass the data as a dependency (because you are using it inside the effect)
```

You can see the updated behaviour here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mendeleev-tx5ck

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put empty array as second arg of useEffect hook:

It is working now. Try this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ChartViewer from "./ChartViewer";

export default function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 30 + 1)) + 30;
      let array = [...data, val];
      console.log(array);
      array.shift();
      updateData(array);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChartViewer data={data} title="Product Trends by Month" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fire-fdw98

Don't forget to clean the setInterval API call when you unmount this component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const upDataFn = seriesUp => {
    switch (seriesUp) {
        case 'ADD':
            ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                usAx.slice(),
                usAx.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1),
                usAx.splice()
            )
            break
        case 'REMOVE':
            if( series.length === 0) return ;
            ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                usAx.slice(),
                usAx.pop()
            )
            break
        case 'RANDOMIZE':
            ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                usAx.map(() => {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1
                })
            )
            break
        case 'RESET':
            ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                usAx 
            )
            break
        default:
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code `    const options = {
    chart: {
        id: 'pie-donut',
        type: 'donut',
        animations: {
            enabled: true,
            easing: 'easeinout',
            speed: 800,
            animateGradually: {
                enabled: true,
                delay: 150
            },
            dynamicAnimation: {
                enabled: true,
                speed: 350
            }
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    },
    colors: colorGroup,
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            expandOnClick: false,
            offsetX: -150,
            offsetY: 10,
            customScale: 1,
            dataLabels: {
                offset: 0,
                minAngleToShowLabel: 10
            },
            donut: {
                size: '55%',
                background: '#111',
                labels: {
                    show: true,
                    name: {
                        show: true,
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        //color: [colorGroup],
                        formatter: val => {
                            return val
                        }
                    },
                    value: {
                        show: true,
                        fontSize: '36px',
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                        fontWeight: '100',
                        color: "#fff",
                        offsetY: 20,
                        formatter: val => {
                            return val
                        }
                    },
                    total: {
                        show: true,
                        showAlways: false,
                        fontSize: '20px',
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                        fontWeight: '300',
                        color: "#fff",
                        label: 'series-1',
                        formatter: w => {
                            return w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce(a => {
                                return a 
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    stroke: {
        colors: ["#222"],
        width: 0
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'left',  
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
        fontWeight: 200,
        inverseOrder: false,  
        offsetX: 6,
        offsetY: -15,
        height: 340,
        labels: {
            colors: ["#fff"]
        },
        markers: {
            width: 12,
            height: 12,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            offsetX: -5,
            offsetY: 10
        },
        itemMargin: {
            horizontal: 15  
        },
        onItemClick: {
            toggleDataSeries: true
        },
        onItemHover: {
            highlightDataSeries: true
        }
    }
};`here
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation in addition to a solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
 export const ApexChartsButtonGroupPie = ({upDataFn}) => {
    return (
        <div className="float-l ml-35 mt-15 apexchart-button-group-pie"> 
            <button onClick={() => upDataFn('ADD')}> + ADD </button>
            <button onClick={() => upDataFn('REMOVE')}>  - REMOVE </button>
            <button onClick={() => upDataFn('RANDOMIZE')}> RANDOMIZE </button>
            <button onClick={() => upDataFn('RESET')}> RESET </button>
        </div>
    )
};

import React from "react"; 
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";
import { useHookAxios } from "../../ds-hooks/use-hook-axios";
import { colorGroup, ApexChartsButtonGroupPie } from "../hook/hook-apexchart";
import "../css/style.css";

export const DsApexChartPieDonutUpdate = () => {
    const url = "../../json-data/ds-chart.json";
    const [
        data,
        isLoading,
        isError ] = useHookAxios(url);
        
    const usAx = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.slice(0, 24).length; i++) {
        usAx.push(data[i].Ax); 
    };

    const series = usAx;

    const options = {
        chart: {
            id: 'pie-donut',
            type: 'donut',
            animations: {
                enabled: true,
                easing: 'easeinout',
                speed: 800,
                animateGradually: {
                    enabled: true,
                    delay: 150
                },
                dynamicAnimation: {
                    enabled: true,
                    speed: 350
                }
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        colors: colorGroup,
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 360,
                expandOnClick: false,
                offsetX: -150,
                offsetY: 10,
                customScale: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    offset: 0,
                    minAngleToShowLabel: 10
                },
                donut: {
                    size: '55%',
                    background: '#111',
                    labels: {
                        show: true,
                        name: {
                            show: true,
                            fontSize: '16px',
                            fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                            fontWeight: '600',
                            //color: [colorGroup],
                            formatter: val => {
                                return val
                            }
                        },
                        value: {
                            show: true,
                            fontSize: '36px',
                            fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                            fontWeight: '100',
                            color: "#fff",
                            offsetY: 20,
                            formatter: val => {
                                return val
                            }
                        },
                        total: {
                            show: true,
                            showAlways: false,
                            fontSize: '20px',
                            fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                            fontWeight: '300',
                            color: "#fff",
                            label: 'series-1',
                            formatter: w => {
                                return w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce(a => {
                                    return a 
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        stroke: {
            colors: ["#222"],
            width: 0
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'left',  
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: 200,
            inverseOrder: false,  
            offsetX: 6,
            offsetY: -15,
            height: 340,
            labels: {
                colors: ["#fff"]
            },
            markers: {
                width: 12,
                height: 12,
                strokeWidth: 0,
                offsetX: -5,
                offsetY: 10
            },
            itemMargin: {
                horizontal: 15  
            },
            onItemClick: {
                toggleDataSeries: true
            },
            onItemHover: {
                highlightDataSeries: true
            }
        }
    };
 
    const upDataFn = seriesUp => {
        switch (seriesUp) {
            case 'ADD':
                ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                    usAx.slice(),
                    usAx.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1),
                    usAx.splice()
                )
                break
            case 'REMOVE':
                if( series.length === 0) return ;
                ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                    usAx.slice(),
                    usAx.pop()
                )
                break
            case 'RANDOMIZE':
                ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                    usAx.map(() => {
                        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1
                    })
                )
                break
            case 'RESET':
                ApexCharts.exec('pie-donut', 'updateSeries',
                    usAx 
                )
                break
            default:
        }
    };
 
    return (
        <section className="section-group">
            <h5 className="float-l group-h5"> DsApexChartPieDonutUpdate - useHookAxios </h5>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-10 push-1">
                        {isError && <div className="float-l w-100 font-s26 c-white font-w1 line-h50"> Something went wrong... </div>}
                        {isLoading ? (
                            <div className="float-l w-100 font-s26 c-white font-w1 line-h50"> Loading Data... </div>
                        ) : (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="donut" height={350} />
                                <ApexChartsButtonGroupPie upDataFn={upDataFn} />
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
};
```